# focusout event get called multiple time. Why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two view one Normal view and another partial view. I have a input field (PersonId) in that partial view (focusout event is in this field). And the partial view will be loaded when there is a change in master view input field (InvestigationId).

My problem is- when the page being loaded first time(partial view also loaded first time) for this the focusout event works perfectly.but when i changed  "InvestigationId" 2nd time or 3rd time or more, the foucsout event get called similar times when the event get fired (PersonId focusout).
My jquery code.

```
$(document).on('focusout','#PersonId',getPersonDetails);
```

Comment: Does `#PersonId` have some child elements? This may be caused by propagation. Could you edit your question to include the HTML.

Comment: Are you binding event handler in partial?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan No i don't have child element under PersonId. The html is simple <input type="text" name="PersonId" id="PersonId" value="@Model.PersonId" class="form-control"/>

Comment: @ Satpal yes, i did it in the partial view.

Comment: Thanks all, I got my solution. I have added those event to the main view. That does the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

May solve your problem..! Not sure.

```
$(document).on('focusout','#PersonId', function(){
    //your code here
    //at the very end of your code just add
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I got my solution. I have added those event to the main view. That does the job for me.